# Spring transaction handling JMSTemplate inside @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jms

In our spring boot application we have a paging loop over the database which will send a JMS message for every page using a `JMSTemplate`. The method containing the loop is `@Transactional`. The `JMSTemplate` is created with the transacted flag set to true.

I have been browsing through the source code of `JMSTemplate` and as far as I can see it will not commit a transacted session if there is already a outer transaction going on but will put it into that transaction.

Let's now consider the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void loopThroughPages(String destination, String from, String to) {
    Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, maxPageSize);
    Page<Event> eventPage;
    do {
       eventPage = eventRepo.getEventsInTimeRangeForDestination(from, to, destination, pageRequest);
       if(eventPage.hasContent()) {
          Message<String> eventMessage = buildEventMessage(eventPage.getContent());
          JmsTemplate template = queueService.createTemplate(destination);
          template.send(eventMessage);
          pageRequest = eventPage.nextPageable();
       }
    } while(pageRequest != null && eventPage.hasNext());
}
```

The `createTemplate` creates a `DynamicJmsTemplate` using a `CachingConnectionFactory` and `setSessionTransacted` to `true`

I am now not entirely sure how this translates to the transactions. My understanding is that all `N` page messages are sent in the transaction created from the `loopThroughPages` and once the `loopThroughPages` method finishes it will commit all `N` messages and not after each message has been sent. That also implies that the transaction on MQ side will stay open until the last page has been processed. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I had removed my comment about `commit` and `close` in the `JmsTemplate` because it does not necessarily close the `Session` it obtained, only if it cannot get a transactional session from `ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is the Transastion managment.

If you use a XA datasource and configure it on your spring boot app you will have a distributed transaction and the commit/rollback for your transaction will be managed by spring since that you have a method annotated with @Transactional otherwise you will have a local transaction managment and the transaction of your database and messaging system will be not syncronized.

For sending message you can by properties configure if the message are persisted or not that it means if your messages will be persisted by your messaging system, while for listener perspective you can configure the acknowledged mode.
By the way the my advice is let to spring managed the transaction and all will be fine but the real point of attention is if you want a distributed transaction between database and jms system you have only configure it atomikos can be an available option, otherwise it is sufficient do not manage the transaction by hand and let to Spring manage it for you.

I hope that it can help you

Comment: That is interesting. Our application is not using XA transactions (so locally transacted), however what I notice in the current issue is that the loop starts at T+00s and at T+42s the MQ system aborts the transaction because it is running for too long and it needs to free log space. The performance of the current paging implementation is poor which would indicate that the transaction of the MQ `Session` is only committed at the end of the loop (or in this case forcefully rolled back by MQ). Is this a contradiction? I am not entirely sure

Comment: It is not a contradiction, because the transaction manager created by the application creates a `ChainedTransactionManager` with the default `JpaTransactionManager` and a `JmsTransactionManager` for each `QueueConnectionFactory` where the transactions use `SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS`. So according to my understanding the transactions will be tied together and the commit will only happen at the end of the loop.